# Install MVC 2 after Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 (final) and then Visual Studio 2008. Now I have to open a project with VS2008 that uses MVC2. Is there any problem to install MVC2 after VS2010?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 comes with MVC2 as standard.

Comment: I know, but I have to use Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET MVC Project Template, then yes you need to install it, otherwise the assemblies are already in the GAC. Also the project you are trying to open must have been created with VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and Install MVC2 , It will install into VS2008 , and it will leave the install of mvc2 in vs2010 alone.  Also if you care, mvc3 works in vs2010 only, and it will install and live separately from mvc2 and allow you to choose from either, and as scottgu and others from microsoft mention, just install the mvc3 tooling update and it will automatically look to see if you have mvc3 install, and install everything if needed.  Once again MVC3 will not uninstall or touch mvc2 from vs2008 or vs2010.

I realize that you are asking about MVC2, so along with helping to answer that question, I thought I help assist with your MVC3 installation.